# Doesn't Show Plugins Tab on my WordPress Account

Tags: wordpress

While I am trying to make a blog, I have been faced a very strange problem.
Basically my blog contains tons of C++/Java code so that it needs auto formatting(Manually its too much tedious). By Googling I had found some good plugins. But the problem is Plugins Tab was not appeared on my wordpress account.
What could I do to get back Plugins Tab? 
Or Is there any alternative solution to set up plugins?
Note1: I used [Big Brother](https://wordpress.com/themes/shubhoshaha.wordpress.com/big-brother/) Theme.
Note2: Wordpress Skill of Mine: Amateur

Comment: Are you an administrator user?

Comment: Yes, I am. 
But is there any way to see whether I'm a Admin or Not.

Comment: Nope. There is a reason for differing user levels, only an administrator has full access to the installation. See http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities

Answer (score -1):

You can check if your admin by viewing all users and next to your username it should say "Administrator" at "Role".

Are you perhaps on a WordPress Multisite installation? In this case the SuperAdmin should add plugins for you.